# How to properly use "x.js" library to format currency?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Im working on a test site, teaching myself how to use Angular and other web technologies. Please disregard "basic-ness" of the whole site, I've given myself about a year to complete it :).

I need to format currency properly i.e. make it look like $ 280,000.00 (I output the amounts using Angular). Page is [HERE](http://testsite.7others.com/shop.php).

What I have found so far is this library "[accounting.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/)" but I dont really understand how to make it all work together. The end goal is this:

1. have a small database (MySQL), with a few products
2. get/ update data with my web app, using one of the technologies (still unsure if Angular is what I'm looking for; if not I can work with PHP somewhat)
3. output data to the view using Angular

Should I and how do I use this .js library? I have included it in the page, now I dont understand where should I call the functions from it.

Thanks!

Comment: why not use currency filter provided by angular

Answer (score 0):

You are using AngularJS, simply use [Angular built-in filter `currency`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) like:

```
{{ amount | currency }}
```

Please check the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ayLzxxsc/